# How to fix TLS handshake timeout when importing rsc.io/quote package in Go?

Tags: go, module, proxy, tls1.2, glide-golang

I’m trying to run a simple hello world program in Go that imports the rsc.io/quote package, but I get this error:

```
    go: finding module for package rsc.io/quote
example/hello imports
        rsc.io/quote: module rsc.io/quote: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/rsc.io/quote/@v/list": net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

I have tried setting the GOPROXY environment variable to direct and https://goproxy.io, but neither of them worked. I have also checked my internet connection and firewall settings, and they seem fine. What could be causing this error and how can I fix it?